# How to swap tasks in a background thread which should do a callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

My app should update its information about a web service. This work should be done in a separate thread. I don't want to do a simply async call from my ViewController because their is a lot of other work which have the thread to do.

If all responses are received and performed the other thread should call a delegate on my ViewController.

Can you give me some tips and rudiments how to implement that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using NSURLConnection, but the code is quite complex.

I've written a simple class for making asynchronous web requests on a background thread. You can find it here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/RequestQueue

It works in a similar way to the NSOperationQueue that jsd suggested (you can actually use it with an NSOperationQueue if you want), but I think you'll find it's easier to use.

Here is how you would make your request from your view controller using my class:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl?foo=bar"]];
[[RequestQueue mainQueue] addRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    //do something with the response

}];
```

Because it uses blocks, you don't need to create a delegate method, you can just put your handling code directly inside the callback (where i've put the "do something with response" comment).

The code inside that callback will be called on the main thread, so it's safe to update your UI in there, however it will be called several seconds after you actually start the request, after it finishes downloading in the background - just like a delegate method.

Comment: +1 for sharing. Out of curiosity, why did you "reimplement" MKNetworkKit/AFNetworking/ASIHTTPRequest? In other words, what makes your implementation distinct from those?

Comment: ASI has been abandoned, AFN doesn't support ARC, and MKN... I'd never heard of until now ;-) Besides which they're all "kitchen sink" solutions - I don't like massive frameworks that do everything, I prefer single-purpose libraries that I can mix and match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSOperationQueue to perform an ordered series of tasks on a background thread.  If you want to update a web service then perform tasks in sequence, you could create a new class that used NSURLConnection to perform the update, then when the NSURLConnection finishes, you could start an NSOperationQueue.